# Javascript function declaration within function with same name

Tags: javascript

I've just seen this pattern in javascript:

```
var test = function () {
    function test(args) {
       this.properties = args || {}; //etc
    }
}

test.prototype.methodName = function (){} //...etc
```

What is going on with the function definition; declared once outside and once inside. What is the value of this approach?